# Динамическое изменение шрифта заголовка UIButton

Tags: xcode, swift, uibutton

Имеем проблему - есть ряд кнопок UIButton сделанных в main.storyboard имеющих tittle. Имеются constrains благодаря которым кнопки увеличиваются в размерах на устройствах с большим экраном. При этом размер шрифта tittle не меняется в результате получаем огромные кнопки с крохотными подписями. Когда устройство с маленьким экраном типа iPhone5 или 4 имеем обратную картину - подписи вылезают за пределы кнопки.
Игрался вариантами

```
@IBAction func touchDigit(_ sender: UIButton) {
        sender.titleLabel?.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5;
        sender.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        sender.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

Сделал для кнопок отдельный класс с инспектабл варами

```
@IBInspectable var adjustFontSize : Bool {
set { titleLabel?.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = newValue }
get { return titleLabel!.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory  }
   }
```

ошибок не дает, но и результата никакого.

В UILabel хотя бы есть чекбокс Automatically adjust fonts, у UIButton такого нет

Английские форумы кроме вышеперечисленного ничего не предлагают.
Может тут кто подскажет.

Answer (score 0):

Если constraint установлена на ширину кнопки, а не на отступы от других вьюшек, то уменьшить шрифт при маленькой кнопке можно так (увеличиваться шрифт при большой ширине не будет):

```
btn.titleLabel!.numberOfLines = 1
btn.titleLabel!.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
btn.titleLabel!.lineBreakMode = .byClipping
```

Либо, в сториборде можно настроить шрифт для различных девайсов: 
[image: настройки для разных устройств сториборд]

Хотя это поможет только при настройке различий между телефоном и планшетом и не решит проблему в разнице между 4s и 6.

Вообще, apple рекомендует делать дизайн так, чтоб выглядело хорошо на всех телефонах с одинаковыми настройками, но если уж очень хочется заточить, можно определять модель устройства и для каждого варианта выдавать свой размер.

Например, так:

https://github.com/dennisweissmann/DeviceKit